# adding multiple states in context provider with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I want to add two states in my context. Not sure how to pass the value for both states `value={ [count, setCount], [percentage, setPercentage] }` is this correct? And also noticed that only the percentage state is working and it overriding my count state for some reason. Any kind of help will be great thank you. My code below

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react'
export const AppContext = createContext()

export const CounterProvider = props => {

const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(20)

return (
    <>
        <AppContext.Provider value={ [count, setCount], [percentage, setPercentage] }>
            {props.children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    </>
)
}
```

My other component as below

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { AppContext } from './AppContext'

const StepOne = () => {

const [percentage, setPercentage] = useContext(AppContext)
const percentageIncrement = () => {
    setPercentage(percentage + 80)
}

const [count, setCount] = useContext(AppContext)
const countIncrement = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options here, the value of your context can either be an array, or an object. I see you are trying to go for the array option and to be done properly it would look like this

```
<AppContext.Provider value={[ [count, setCount], [percentage, setPercentage] ]}>
  {props.children}
</AppContext.Provider>
```

```
const [[count, setCount], [percentage, setPercentage]] = useContext(AppContext)
```

OR

The more common way is to have an object with meaningful keys

```
<AppContext.Provider value={{ count, setCount, percentage, setPercentage }}>
  {props.children}
</AppContext.Provider>

// this is equal to

<AppContext.Provider value={{ count: count, setCount: setCount, percentage: percentage, setPercentage: setPercentage }}>
  {props.children}
</AppContext.Provider>
```

```
const {count, setCount, percentage, setPercentage} = useContext(AppContext)
```

Comment: Many thanks this worked for me. I used the common way object destructuring make more sense. Thanks again!

Comment: @HassanHafez Always happy to help, glad to hear this solution worked.